# Ignore item in FileList Delphi

Tags: delphi, listview, file-manager, filelist

I'm making simple file manager, using Delphi. I use `ListView` to show folders and files and I use `FileList`(it's not visible) to get files and folders names from some directory.

The problem is that I want to not include this `[.]` element (it's symbol of current dir, don't know why Delphi's `FileList` shows it) in ListView. But, when I try to ignore it(here's code)

```
procedure TfolderFrame.ShowFiles;
var
  i: Integer;
  size: int64;
  fileName, extension: string;
begin
  edt1.Text := CurrentFullPath;
  lvListView.Clear;
  fllstFiles.Directory := CurrentFullPath;

  For i := 0 To fllstFiles.Items.Count-1 Do begin
    fileName := fllstFiles.Items.Strings[i];
   extension := UpperCase(ExtractFileExt(fileName));
    size := DSiFileSize(fileName);
    Delete(extension, 1, 1);

    if (fileName <> '[.]') then begin //error apperas at this line!

      if (not(isDirectory(fileName))) then begin
        lvListView.Items.Add.Caption := fileName;
        lvListView.Items[i].SubItems.Add(IntToStr(size));
        lvListView.Items[i].SubItems.Add(extension);
        lvListView.Items[i].ImageIndex := GetItemImage(fileName, extension);
      end
      else begin
        Delete(fileName, 1, 1);
        Delete(fileName, Length(fileName), 1);
        lvListView.Items.Add.Caption := fileName;
        lvListView.Items[i].ImageIndex := GetItemImage(fileName, extension);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

an error appers

> Access violation at address 004634DF in module file_manager.exe. Read
>   of adress 00000010

What I've done wrong?

Comment: Why not use `FindFirst` / `FindNext`?

Comment: Please don't make us guess which like the error occurs on. Tell us. And you spell it *extension* rather than *extention*. And yes, don't use a GUI control to list files in a directory. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: @JerryDodge well, I never use it before ._.

Comment: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FindNext

Comment: Does the error only occur if you check for `[.]`? It's unclear from your question. And there's not enough code shown to indicate that you created the FileList object, etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah, sorry, I will fix words(not native spkr). But error occurs when there are `filename ='[.]'` and  these statement  `if (fileName <> '[.]')` is gonna execute

Comment: @mbratch it works fine when I not ignore it

Comment: @mbratch I guess I do created FileList object 
http://i.imgur.com/TWhuC6s.png

Comment: Fix the question rather than commenting

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, I thought that it's not necessary if it marked as answered, but, well, okay

Comment: It's advice for next time as much as anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not adding an item in each iteration in the for loop. When you skip for `[.]`, you should get an AV for `lvlistview.items[i]` in the next iteration, because the index of the item you just added is `i-1`. To resolve, keep a reference to the item you add and work on it.

```
var
  ..
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  ..
        Item := lvListView.Items.Add;
        Item.Caption := fileName;
        Item.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(size));
        Item.SubItems.Add(extention);
        Item.ImageIndex := GetItemImage(fileName, extention);
      ..
```